# Recyclerview section title is not visible when updating the list with filtered result

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I update the recyclerview list in the fragment the section title doesnt show up. What should I do? I have checked the recyclerview adapter it is working fine the problem might be in the fragment.May be the fragment doesnt know where to put the view when the fragment is updated.

Can anyone please help me with this

Here is my fragment code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    setRetainInstance(true);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_leads, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, mRootView);
    GlowShipApplication.getAppComponent().inject(this);
    mLeadListPresenter.setView(this);
    mSysPrefs = SystemAppPreferences.getInstance(getActivity());
    mProgressBarHandler = new ProgressBarHandler(getActivity());


    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mData = getArguments().getString("fragmentName");

    }


    return mRootView;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String token = mSysPrefs.getToken();

    if (ConnectionInfo.isConnectingToInternet(getActivity())) {
        // api call


        mLeadListPresenter.fetchLeadList(token);



        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // mProgressBarHandler.show();
        rvLeads.setVisibility(View.GONE);




    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.no_internet_connection),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    initComponent();


}




private void initComponent() {


    rvLeads.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    rvLeads.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLeadList = new ArrayList<>();
    //set data and list adapter
    mAdapter = new AdapterLeads(getActivity(), mLeadList);
    rvLeads.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterLeads.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, Data obj, int position) {
            mProgressBarHandler.hide();
            // need to move site survey detail
            if (position > -1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SiteSurveyStatusActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("homeOwnerID", mAdapter.getList().get(position)
                        .getData().getHomeownerId());
                intent.putExtra("dealer_status_code",mAdapter.getList().get(position)
                        .getData().getDealerStatusCode());
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);

            }



        }
    });



}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_view_menu, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            startActivity(getActivity().getIntent());

            return false;
        }
    });

}





@OnClick(R.id.fab)
public void createLead(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LeadActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onSuccessFetchLeadList(LeadList leadList) {
    mProgressBarHandler.hide();

    if (leadList != null) {
        rvLeads.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        noRecordFoundImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mLeadList.clear();


        if (mData != null) {


            if (mData.contains("proposals")) {

                View view = rvLeads.getChildAt(0);
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccessFetchLeadList: " + view);
                ArrayList<Datum> filterdNames = new ArrayList<>();

                //looping through existing elements
                for (Datum s : leadList.getData()) {
                    //if the existing elements contains the search input
                    if (!s.getIstitle())
                        if (s.getData().getStatusId().contains("P3") ||
                                s.getData().getStatusId().contains("P4") ||
                                s.getData().getStatusId().contains("P5") ||
                                s.getData().getStatusId().contains("P6") ||
                                s.getData().getStatusId().contains("P7") ||
                                s.getData().getStatusId().contains("P8")) {
                            //adding the element to filtered list
                            filterdNames.add(s);
                            mLeadList.addAll(filterdNames);
                            Set<Datum> setList = new LinkedHashSet<>(mLeadList);
                            mLeadList.clear();
                            mLeadList.addAll(setList);
                        }


                }

            } else if (mData.contains("installations")) {
                //to be continued latter
                ArrayList<Datum> filterdNames = new ArrayList<>();

                //looping through existing elements
                for (Datum s : leadList.getData()) {
                    //if the existing elements contains the search input
                    if (!s.getIstitle())
                        if (s.getData().getStatusId().contains("S11")) {
                            //adding the element to filtered list
                            filterdNames.add(s);
                            mLeadList.addAll(filterdNames);
                            Set<Datum> setList = new LinkedHashSet<>(mLeadList);
                            mLeadList.clear();
                            mLeadList.addAll(setList);


                        } else {
                            noRecordFoundImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                }
            } else if (mData.contains("leads")) {
                mLeadList.addAll(leadList.getData());
            }


        } else {
            mLeadList.addAll(leadList.getData());
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}


@Override
public void onError(LeadList leadList) {

    mProgressBarHandler.hide();
}


@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    List<Datum> filter = filter(mLeadList, newText);
    mAdapter.filteredList(filter);
    return false;
}


//Helper method to filter out the leads list
private List<Datum> filter(List<Datum> mLeadList, String newText) {
    //new array list that will hold the filtered data
    ArrayList<Datum> filterdNames = new ArrayList<>();

    //looping through existing elements
    for (Datum s : mLeadList) {
        //if the existing elements contains the search input
        if (!s.getIstitle())
            if (s.getData().getName().contains(newText)) {
                //adding the element to filtered list
                filterdNames.add(s);
            }
    }

    //calling a method of the adapter class and passing the filtered list
    mAdapter.filteredList(filterdNames);
    return filterdNames;
}
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="in.thelattice.glowship.dealer.leadslist.LeadsFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_leadlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollingCache="false" />


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/nodata"
    android:id="@+id/noRecordFoundIv"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/appYellowColor"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
```

Comment: Please add only relevant code, also, can you add your xml layout?

Comment: this is the relevant code. yes i will